# Acceptable Hashes by shadow

Tags: password, php, encryption, hash, shadow

What hash algorithms does /etc/shadow accept?

I've tried generating password hashes from PHP, using `password_hash("password1234", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`, but that doesn't seem to work when I try to authenticate once I replace a user's password to the hash provided by the hashes I generate with PHP.

Any reason why blowfish doesn't work? (I think PHP uses blowfish by default)

Comment: You should probably not be recreating the wheel. Ubuntu's default method is SHA512 . Although I can not find the documentation, I do not think you can use blowfish, MD5, or SHA256 any longer as they are considered insecure.

Answer (score 2):

Passwords are hashed using the library function`crypt(3)`; see the manual page for [`crypt(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/crypt.3.html). The function chooses the encryption function based on the format of the *salt*:

- `$1$`*salt_chars*`$`: use MD5
- `$2a$`*salt_chars*`$`: use Blowfish (not standard, most likely not available)
- `$5$`*salt_chars*`$`: use SHA-256
- `$6$`*salt_chars*`$`: use SHA-512
- Not in the form `$`*type*`$`*salt_chars*`$`: use DES as in the old days.

I have no idea if you can use PHP to emulate exactly what `crypt(3)` does.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried generating password hashes from PHP, using `password_hash("password1234", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`...

Then you need to save the output in the format that `/etc/shadow` expects, which, as explained by AlexP, is:

```
$<method>$<salt>$<hash>
```

`password_hash`'s output is different. It returns:

```
$<method>$<cost>$<hash>
```

For example, a password of `a` (`password_hash("a", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`) outputs, for me:

```
$2y$10$w4hgkTWvE37igKd9TMn8xOcCNT/L/lojOEkqaPyIW4qdyAp92GmHC
```

And the salt is weirdly part of the hash:

```
password_hash("a", PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt'=>'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'])
// $2y$10$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuuj/LkVFwQAC6H0GkC0f1Bcmj82rKvDn.
```

But the `shadow` version is:

```
$6$OaeCC6PI$qGI4OTUD/seGOvJE.ckkrWMoqiVQBf8EXtQFto7MsKP8TyTCxPXPF66csX3c4ljdRnjM1U8W65EpwUgMF.4qf0
```

See the salt in the second field?

Anyway, I don't know what PHP is doing here. You should probably use [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), but I'm no PHP expert and that's a question for SO.

Also, for me, `man crypt` reports that `2y` is not understood by it:

```
If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"  fol-
lowed by a string terminated by "$":

      $id$salt$encrypted

then  instead  of  using  the DES machine, id identifies the encryption
method used and this then determines  how  the  rest  of  the  password
string is interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:

      ID  | Method
      ---------------------------------------------------------
      1   | MD5
      2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
          | Linux distributions)
      5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
      6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
```