# Migrating servers

Tags: 18.04, password, authentication, hash

For my sins I am assisting a friend in migrating from a 10 year old SuSE mail server to one running Ubuntu-18.04.

One of the things I need to do is migrate over about a dozen or so users--several of which are severely impaired when it comes to this interwebs/computer thing (think friend and elderly family).

What I have done in the past--and what I am trying to do now--is to simply lift the hash string out of /etc/shadow on one box and drop it into the new server whole.

Most of these users *never* log in to the server via the commandline, they only access it through IMAP or POP3 clients (including Courier SqWebMail).

However this isn't working this time.

I suspect that this is because the SuSE server used Blowfish as the hashing algorithm. The hashes on that server all start with $2a or $2y, which this snippet of man crypt_r states is Blowfish:

```
  ID  | Method
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  1   | MD5
  2a  | Blowfish, system-specific on 8-bit chars
  2y  | Blowfish, correct handling of 8-bit chars
```

All I can find close to this subject is something like this: 
[How to change password encoding to blowfish for nis client using auth-client-config at ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026406/how-to-change-password-encoding-to-blowfish-for-nis-client-using-auth-client-con) and [Acceptable Hashes by shadow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979954/acceptable-hashes-by-shadow) which don't really have answers.

I've tried editing `/etc/pam.d/common-password` to include a line that says:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure blowfish
```

but it didn't change the behavior.

My question is how do I get the current hashes to work under Ubuntu-18.04--once that is done I can force updates to better hash algorithms.

My fall back plan is to generate passwords for the users and have my friend hand them out.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is using SHA512 according to /etc/login.defs and /etc/pam.d/common-password. Also libpam-unix seems to have gone away.

Comment: Also, edited the question.