# When changing the password for a user on my system, why does the size of /etc/shadow never get bigger or smaller?

Tags: passwd

When changing the password for a user on my Ubuntu system, I've noticed that no matter the length of the password that I choose the /etc/shadow file will always stay the same size and never increase/decrease.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why should it? It doesn't contain passwords.

Comment: If you add another user, it should increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's saved as a **hash** and hashes of the same algorithm are the same length no matter what.

In Ubuntu I think the default algorithm for user passwords is `sha512`, which, as the name implies is always 512bit = 86byte long.

See:

- https://www.aychedee.com/2012/03/14/etc_shadow-password-hash-formats/
- [What is the length of a hashed string with SHA512?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236106/what-is-the-length-of-a-hashed-string-with-sha512)
- [Acceptable Hashes by shadow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979954/acceptable-hashes-by-shadow)

Comment: Thank you - and for your help everybody else. :)

Answer (score 2):

The password is converted to a hash and that is a one way process.

So when you enter a password it will be converted to a hash and the hash will be compared with the hash in `/etc/shadow` and if it is a match you have entered the correct password.

Ref.: https://www.aychedee.com/2012/03/14/etc_shadow-password-hash-formats/